# Tinymce content clear mceCleanup

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to clear tinymce content and add new content. i tried with following code but its getting append to the old content. how can clear the existing content from tinymce.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceCleanup');
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, result.content);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use :

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
```

> Sets the specified content to the editor instance, this will cleanup
>   the content before it gets set using the different cleanup rules
>   options.

Reference:[TinyMce](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Documentation is sometimes just too comprehensive to comprehend..!!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: if so, explain this to me `different cleanup rules options` where are those options listed?

Comment: @jimasun: I believe you still haven't taken a look at the documentation page linked in the answer... There are pretty clear examples listed explaining the "different cleanup rules".

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: I did and all I can see is two examples: `format: 'bbcode'` and `format : 'bbcode'`. I know there are other options such as `text` and `html` but I can't find the documentation for it.

Comment: @jimasun: I don't quite get what docs are you looking for!! format sets the editor syntax support for `html` or `bbcode` or `raw text`. `html` uses html syntax, `raw` uses plain text and `bbcode` uses bbcode syntax. Does [this example](http://archive.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/bbcode.php) for bbcode help?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Sorry I didn't mentioned it but, in my case I need the format so I can `getContent()`. I needed the `raw` \ `text` format. I was curious where I can find a full list of them -- not just figuring out from 2 examples.

Comment: @jimasun Well, comments feature is not to ask questions or give answers, so I suggest you open a new thread to post your question and the context with code in detail, if you still have doubts.

Comment: This will not reset the header to be empty when using fullpage plugin.

Comment: The reference link no longer takes you to a relevant page.

Answer (score 5):

To clear existing content, try

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("");
```

and then add the desired content using the same [`setContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent) method:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(result.content);
```

There is a known [bug](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=13821) with this in webkit that it loses focus on the textarea but a workaround would be to put this in a setup or init-callback:

```
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
setup : function(ed) {
    if(tinymce.isWebKit) {
        //workaround for Webkit to fix focus problems when setting contents to an empty string
        ed.onSetContent.add(function() {
            window.focus();
            ed.focus();
        });                        
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Here the new Link: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Comment: @sneaky Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

TinyMCE provides a method setContent.  Use this method to set new value.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("content");
```

Similarly it provides getContent()

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are having multiple TinyMCE editors, you can use:

```
$('textarea').each(function(k, v) {
    tinyMCE.get(k).setContent('');
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/fx2gmu3h/9/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `id` for the `textarea` then you can get the `editor` with the `id` of the `textarea`.

```
<textarea id='editor'></textarea>
//tinyMCE.get(**id of the textarea**).setContent('');
tinyMCE.get('editor').setContent('');
```

Comment: Even though the OP did not ask about getting a named Editor, I personally find this to be much more helpful.  Way too many many resources talking about tinyMCE just assume that you are only working with one input per page load.